# In Logan Lucky, what was the explosion for?

Tags: plot-explanation, logan-lucky

During the heist in **Logan Lucky**, Joe Bang sends a homemade explosive mixture through a pneumatic tube into the money room. How does the explosive allow them to suck money out of the room?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a door or valve at the end of the pneumatic tube that closes after each batch of money is dropped into the vault.  While that door is closed, pulling air out of the tube will not pull money out of the vault.  When the door is destroyed by the explosive, air and money can be pulled through the tube.